# How to query database for log in form in Visual Studio+Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Trying to learn Visual Studio, I was able to create a static log in form e.g. check if the text box and password match the hard coded data, but I just cannot get the Access query to work. I've ran through 6 different efforts (cleared them all until this point)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Login

Dim con As New OleDbConnection

Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\someone\source\repos\Test\Test\vs.mdb"
    con.Open()
    Dim logincmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * From tblLogin WHERE userName = " & tbUser.Text, con)
    Dim loginrd As OleDbDataReader = logincmd.ExecuteReader

    If (loginrd.Read() = True) Then
        MenuPage.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Sorry that's not right")
    End If


End Sub
```

Error: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'`
On line: `Dim loginrd As OleDbDataReader = logincmd.ExecuteReader`

Please tell me where I'm going wrong?

EDIT: I've found some code that works, so I'm going to cross reference the two and try work out why the above code didn't work, might help me get a better understanding of things!

Comment: You can consider providing the design of your database, so that it will help others analyze your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database objects like `Connection`s and `Command`s need to be disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this for us. They  both declare and dispose the objects.   In this code both the connection and command are handled by a single `Using` block. Note the comma on the first line of the `Using`.

You can pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection. You can also pass the `CommandText` and `Connection` directly to the constructor of the command. A constructor will be indicated by the `New` keyword.

**Always** use parameters to help defeat sql injection. Parameters will not be treated as executable code by the database.

Don't open the connection until directly before the `Execute` statement and close and dispose as soon as possible with `End Using`.

Since we are only seeking a single piece of data (the count) we can use `ExecuteScalar` which returns the first column of the first row of the result set.

```
Private ConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\someone\source\repos\Test\Test\vs.mdb"

Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    'Validate input
    If txtUserName.Text = "" OrElse txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in both Name and Password.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ValidateLogin(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text) Then
        MenuPage.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ValidateLogin(uName As String, pWord As String) As Boolean
    Dim IsValid As Boolean
    Dim ReturnValue As Integer
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConnStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Count(*) From tblLogin Where userName = @UserName AND passWord = @Password;", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = uName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pWord
        cn.Open()
        ReturnValue = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    If ReturnValue = 1 Then
        IsValid = True
    End If
    Return IsValid
End Function
```

Of course, you should **never** store passwords as plain text. Investigate encryption and salting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

- Separating login code from form code
- Never use string concatenation for SQL parameters, use command parameters.
- Encrypting the database
- `If exception.Message.ToLower.Contains("not a valid password") Then` in this case is for an encrypted database, ignore if not encrypting the database.

Recommend a class for login (table columns shown are different from yours but the logic will work no matter)

**Login class**

Permits three attempts at a login.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class ApplicationLogin

    Private ReadOnly ConnectionString As String
    Public Property UserName As String
    Public Property UserPassword As String
    Public Property Retries As Integer

    Private Userid As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property UserIdentifier As Integer
        Get
            Return Userid
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(pConnectionString As String)
        ConnectionString = pConnectionString
    End Sub

    Public Function Login() As Boolean

        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.UserName) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.UserPassword) Then
            Using cn As New OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = ConnectionString}

                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand With
                    {
                    .Connection = cn,
                    .CommandText =
                        "SELECT Identifer, UserName, UserPassword FROM Users " &
                        "WHERE UserName = @UserName AND UserPassword = @UserPassword"
                    }

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = UserName
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = UserPassword


                    Try
                        cn.Open()
                    Catch exception As Exception
                        If exception.Message.ToLower.Contains("not a valid password") Then
                            Return False
                        Else
                            Throw
                        End If
                    End Try


                    Dim reader = cmd.ExecuteScalar

                    If reader IsNot Nothing Then
                        Userid = CInt(reader)
                        Retries = 0

                        Return True
                    Else
                        Retries += 1
                        Return False
                    End If

                End Using
            End Using
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

**Form code**

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Retries As Integer = 0
    Private Sub LoginButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

        Dim appLogin As New ApplicationLogin("Your connection string") With
                {.UserName = txtUserName.Text, .UserPassword = txtPassword.Text}
        If appLogin.Login Then
            ' login successful
        Else
            Retries += 1
            ' too many retries
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Full source** (not done with .mdb but .accdb)

- [Front end](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases/tree/master/LoginFrontEnd)  project
- [Class project](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases/tree/master/LoginLibrary) for login logic
- [Database encryption](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/WorkingWithAccessDatabases#encryption-notes) docs